# C99 casting to a multi-dimensional array in MSVC

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, visual-studio-2015, c99, dynamic-memory-allocation

Consider the following matrix declaration:

```
typedef struct {
    uint32_t rows;
    uint32_t cols;
    uint8_t *data;
} matrix8;

// A function to allocate above matrix.
matrix8 * matrix8_alloc(uint32_t rows, uint32_t cols);
```

I use the following macro to make the access to an `[x][y]` location in the matrix easier:

```
#define GET_M8(m)    ((uint8_t (*)[m->cols])m->data)

matrix8 *m = matrix8_alloc(100, 100);
uint8_t val = GET_M8(m)[x][y];
```

This works fine when compiling with gcc and clang. It also seems like it's C99 compliant (original idea for this usage came from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381711/how-to-declare-a-variable-size-2d-array-in-c)).

However, when it's time to compile with MSVC (cl.exe v19.00.23506), I get the following errors with regards to that macro:

```
error C2057: expected constant expression
error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
error C2036: 'uint8_t (*)[0]': unknown size
```

The question is, does MSVC lack support in this area? Is the above cast portable?

Comment: Yes, Microsoft generally only implements C features beyond C89 when they are also C++ features.

Comment: My own research into this topic is yielding similar conclusions. Feel free to post this as an answer.